# Gratis Serial Port component for Delphi XE8 or Lazarus IDE

Tags: gratis, delphi, lazarus-ide, serial-port

Does anyoen know of one? Not by Googling, but one that you use yourself.

Comment: Is it just because I have no idea what you're talkking about (due to my not being familiar with this field), and this really contains [enough information](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)? I know, many details are in the tags… But still, only one line?

Comment: @Izzy Yes it's you alas. For anyone programming in Delphi (or Lazarus) this is perfectly clear.

Comment: Thanks, Jan (+1) Izzy, this is totally anyone who uses such a component as requested. Any more detail would just muddy the question.

Comment: OK, thanks @JanDoggen and Mawg. Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [TCiaComport](http://www.mestdagh.biz/index.html?redirTo=soft_frame_intro.html&redir2To=/soft_components.html) for years with great success with Delphi.